# Why is Rspec's 'expect to receive' capturing only the first occurrence?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

## Background

This is a command-line program.

I've got a function for capturing user input via `gets`, which I'm using to validate input before returning it.

I've got a `#pick_names` method.

```rb
 def pick_names
        @player_one = get_input("\nPlayer 1, choose a unique name (1-7 alphanumeric characters)", /[A-Za-z0-9]{1,7}$/)
        puts "\nHi, #{@player_one}! Your coin will be #{@player_one_coin}"
        
        loop do
            @player_two = get_input("\nPlayer 2, choose a unique name (1-7 alphanumeric characters)", /[A-Za-z0-9]{1,7}$/)
            break if @player_two != @player_one
        end 
        
        puts "\nHello, #{@player_two}! Your coin will be #{@player_two_coin}"
    end
```

All it's supposed to be doing is ensuring the two names aren't the same.

In my spec for this function, I've got the following:

```rb
    describe '#pick_names' do 
        context 'when picking names' do
            let(:names) { ['bob', 'bob', 'bob', 'ok'] }
            
            it 'rejects duplicates' do
                expect(game).to receive(:get_input).with('choose a unique name').at_least(:once)
                play
            end
        end
    end
```

`names` is a lazy loaded variable that partly makes up the `args` used for each test. It's part of this:

```rb
    let(:args) { ['y', *names, *moves] }
```

## Issue

On that `#pick_names` test, Rspec seems to be comparing my expected input 'choose  unique name' with the text used in the first usage of `get_input`, i.e. `Are you ready to begin? (y/n)`, hence why `args`'s first parameter is a `'y'`.

I understand the 'choose a unique name' string won't be matched anyway as the string contains more than just that. I can modify that later. But why is it picking up on the first usage of `get_input` instead of saying no match was found?

Comment: Hey Barry, I think you're going to have to post some more of the code. For example, where is game defined in your spec? Is it a test double?

Comment: Absolutely. I didn't want to pollute the question but I realise I might've made it more difficult. I've pasted Game to codeshare, hoping I'm not violating any rules: https://codeshare.io/BA4Xwy

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the issue is you are trying to match on a part of the string, not the full input.

```
"\nPlayer 1, choose a unique name (1-7 alphanumeric characters)" != 'choose a unique name'
```

For debugging, try doing the exact string for player 1 and see if it catches that input.

If that works, you'll need some regex to tell RSpec to explicitly match.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Yes, I put in a bit the OP explaining this.